# Error compiling latex-table from semTable package

Tags: compiling, texmaker, r, compilation-error

I'm trying to compile a PDF in texmaker with a table from the semTable-package in R. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error when doing so. Since I'm a massive greenhorn with LaTex, I would be very happy for some trouble shooting advice. It's probably a joke for skilled LaTex-ers. Here is my code, which I reduced to only show the relevant parts:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}r*{4}{S[
                         input-symbols = ( ) +,
                         group-digits = false,
                         table-number-alignment = center,
                         %table-space-text-pre = (,
                         table-align-text-pre = false,
                         table-align-text-post = false,
                         table-space-text-post = {***},
                         parse-units = false]}@{}}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Model}\tabularnewline \hline
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Estimate}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Err.}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{z}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{p}\tabularnewline\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\underline{Factor Loadings}}\tabularnewline \multicolumn{1}{l}{\underline{ABU}}\tabularnewline
NoSKMSM& 1.00$^+$& & & \tabularnewline
KSMChrMX& 0.69& 0.03& 25.78& .000\tabularnewline
KSMSevMx& 0.68& 0.02& 31.20& .000\tabularnewline
 \multicolumn{1}{l}{\underline{NEG}}\tabularnewline
NoSNeg& 1.00$^+$& & & \tabularnewline
NegChrMX& 0.98& 0.03& 31.03& .000\tabularnewline
NegSevMx& 1.11& 0.05& 23.19& .000\tabularnewline
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\underline{Fit Indices}}\tabularnewline
$\chi^{2}(\mathrm{df})$& 7944.00& & & \tabularnewline
CFI& 0.55& & & \tabularnewline
RMSEA& 0.19& & & \tabularnewline
SRMR& 0.16& & & \tabularnewline
Scaled $\chi^{2}(\mathrm{df})$& 2872.83(302)& & & .000\tabularnewline
\hline\multicolumn{5}{l}{$^+$Fixed parameter}\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to ReX SX! You need to load `siunitx` if you want the `S` column type be defined. Unrelated: needless to load `amsfonts` if you load `amssymb`: the latter does it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Silly question: how can I manually add siunitx to my packages. Texmaker does not seem to find it (online).

Comment: If it is not installed,  do it with your package manager. What is your distribution?

Comment: Windows. It seems, that there is a problem with creating a local package repository. I'm not 100% sure I get how to set it up, though.

Comment: Excuse me, but Windows is the O.S., not a LaTeX distribution. Do you have TeX Live or MiKTeX, which are the two main distributions?

Comment: Sorry, MiKTex...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112790/discussion-between-jan-and-bernard).